# Do Ignite support logback for distributed compute？

Tags: spring-boot, logback, ignite

I try to use spring boot (2.1.0.RELEASE) to run ignite.compute. As spring boot + lombok use logback as default, the following codes always throw exceptions (2020-05-28 07:00:48.979  WARN 8460 --- [        p2p-#49] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDeploymentCommunication  : Failed to resolve class: ch.qos.logback). The result (28) could be returned. Seems we see log4j and log4j2 on official website. Does ignite support logback?

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

default-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="igniteCfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="48500"/>
                <property name="localPortRange" value="20"/>
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>127.0.0.1:48500..48520</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="48100"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

java code:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(locations={"classpath:default-config.xml"})
public class IgniteConfig {

    @Bean
    public Ignite ignite(IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration) {
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);
        return ignite;
    }
}

@Slf4j
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    private Ignite ignite;

    @GetMapping("/compute")
    public void compute() {
        Collection<IgniteCallable<Integer>> calls = new ArrayList<>();

        // Iterate through all the words in the sentence and create Callable jobs.
        for (final String word : "Count characters using callable".split(" "))
            calls.add(word::length);

        // Execute collection of Callables on the grid.
        Collection<Integer> res = ignite.compute().call(calls);

        // Add up all the results.
        int sum = res.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

        log.info("Total number of characters is '" + sum + "'.");
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
2020-05-28 07:00:48.786  INFO 8460 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDeploymentLocalStore     : Class locally deployed: class com.sonic.sample.springboot.controller.WebController
2020-05-28 07:00:48.890  WARN 8460 --- [        p2p-#49] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDeploymentCommunication  : Failed to resolve class: ch.qos.logback

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.processResourceRequest(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:216) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.processDeploymentRequest(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:152) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.access$000(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:55) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication$1.onMessage(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:88) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1843) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5100(GridIoManager.java:229) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$8.run(GridIoManager.java:1325) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2020-05-28 07:00:49.000  WARN 8460 --- [        p2p-#50] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDeploymentCommunication  : Failed to resolve class: ch.qos.logback

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.processResourceRequest(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:216) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.processDeploymentRequest(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:152) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.access$000(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:55) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication$1.onMessage(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:88) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1843) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5100(GridIoManager.java:229) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$8.run(GridIoManager.java:1325) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2020-05-28 07:00:49.000  WARN 8460 --- [        p2p-#50] o.a.i.i.m.d.GridDeploymentCommunication  : Failed to resolve class: ch.qos.logback

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.processResourceRequest(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:216) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.processDeploymentRequest(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:152) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication.access$000(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:55) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentCommunication$1.onMessage(GridDeploymentCommunication.java:88) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1843) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5100(GridIoManager.java:229) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$8.run(GridIoManager.java:1325) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2020-05-28 07:00:49.025  INFO 8460 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.s.controller.WebController         : Total number of characters is '28'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an explicit logback dependency to project / Apache Ignite classpath?

Otherwise, you can use

```
@LoggerResource
private IgniteLogger logger;
```

instead of `@Slf4j` on your compute classes.

Comment: I add logback dependency explicitly, but the same error are thrown.

Comment: I added logback dependency explicitly, but the same error was thrown.

       <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

I also try below. It doesn't work. NullPointException...
 @LoggerResource
    private IgniteLogger logger;

Comment: Can you please throw together a runnable reproducer project, put it to e.g. github?

Comment: Thanks.

I submitted my codes into github. You can pull, run and find the issue. (https://github.com/AK47Sonic/ignite_demo)

1. Run com.sonic.sample.springboot.WebBootstrap
2. Access http://localhost:8080/compute

Comment: I also raised an jira on ignite. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13094

Comment: Yes, there seem to be a bug in Apache Ignite, I will try to devise a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why the entire logback would not peer class load (I will check that), BUT

I don't recommend relying on it, instead adding your dependencies' JARs to your server node classpath. I did that by issuing

```
~/ignite_demo% mvn dependency:copy-dependencies 
... Maven downloads dependencies ...
~/ignite_demo% cp -R target/dependency ~/apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin/libs
```

After that, I have restarted my server node, it was able to see dependencies' JARs and http://localhost:8080/compute worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks. It will be fixed on 2.9 version.

issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13094